# Executing a remote command over an SSH tunnel

Tags: ssh, bash

I have created a reverse SSH tunnel from computerB to computerA. On computerA I have a script (`r1on.sh`) with the following content:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'r1on' > command.log
/usr/bin/ssh -p2222 pi@localhost 'sudo /home/pi/bin/relay1On.sh'
```

If I execute this from a bash terminal on computerA, it works - the remote command is successful on computerB.

However, I want to call `r1on.sh` on computerA from my android phone, using [piConnect](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.mwmbb.multiRpiController), which is just an app that uses SSH to connect to computerA and executes a command. When I execute this on the phone, I know it does something because `command.log` is written to, but the remote command through the tunnel is not executed. What's going wrong here?

**Edit with output redirects:**

```
/usr/bin/ssh -p2222 pi@localhost 'sudo /home/pi/bin/relay1On.sh > /tmp/Bout.log' > /tmp/Aout.log
```

On computerA, `/tmp/Aout.log` is created, but empty.
On computerB, `/tmp/Bout.log` is not created.

Comment: Why not redirect the sudo to a file too, so you can see what output its generating when you hit it from your iPhone?

Comment: Currently you do not log stderr. Could you please add please add 2>&1: `sudo /home/pi/bin/relay1On.sh > /tmp/Bout.log 2>&1'` I didn't notice that it was several days ago.